# Task is hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, javafx

When i run the application through IntelliJ (last version) my last task is hanging forever. 
Actually i tried to debug and it is hanging on the fetchRegisterCourseList().
I can see its hanging because i have a progress indicator and the particular data is never acquired.
In the other hand, when i package my application to a jar and execute it normally it does never hang and everything works fine.

Is this an IntelliJ or code related bug?

AuthController:

```
        ... // previous tasks

        Task<List<Course>> parseGradesTask = new Task<List<Course>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Course> call() {
                return studentParser.parseStudentGrades();
            }
        };

        Task<HashMap<String, String>> parseRegTask = new Task<HashMap<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public HashMap<String, String> call() {
                return studentParser.parseStudentRegistration();
            }
        };

        parseGradesTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            serializeService.serializeCourses(parseGradesTask.getValue());
            progressIndicator.setProgress(0.6);
        });

        parseRegTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            // it is hanging at this line:
            List<Course> regList = serializeService.fetchRegisterCourseList(parseGradesTask.getValue(), parseRegTask.getValue());
            serializeService.serializeRegister(regList);
            updateMainComponents();
        });

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        es.submit(parseInfoTask);
        es.submit(parseGradesTask);
        es.submit(parseStatsTask);
        es.submit(parseRegTask);
        es.shutdown();

private void updateMainComponents() {
    MainController.getInstance().updateAllViewComponents();

    if (preferenceService.getPreferences().getPrefSyncEnabled()) {
        SyncScheduler.getInstance().stopScheduler();
        SyncScheduler.getInstance().startSyncScheduler(preferenceService.getPreferences().getPrefSyncTime());
    }
    dialogStage.close(); //close this window
}
```

serializeService:

```
public List<Course> fetchRegisterCourseList(List<Course> courseList, HashMap<String, String> courseIdList) {
    List<Course> courseRegList = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator it = courseIdList.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        courseRegList.addAll(courseList.stream().filter(course ->
                course.getCourseId().equals(pair.getKey()) && course.getCourseTitle().equals(pair.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    return courseRegList;
}
```

Comment: IDK what all those statements are doing, but the expensive tasks should be done in the `call` method of the `Task`s. I don't see you getting any result from the `onSucceeded` handlers, which seems even more weird. Guessing from the method names the `updateMainComponents();` should be the only thing executed in teh `onSucceeded` handler for `parseRegTask`.

Comment: Thanks fabian. It seems that solved my problem. You can write that as the answer to close this question if you wish. Although i'm curious to find out why that was happening (even hypothetically).

Comment: Definitely not an IntelliJ bug. Doubt yourself first, last, and always.

Comment: I'am, that's why i posted here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSuceeded` handler gets called on the JavaFX application thead. No long-running operations should be done here. It's best to only do the UI updates here. The result of a `Task` can be used to "publish" the results of the operations. This value can be retrieved in the `onSucceeded` handler.

In your code you're running those operation in the `onSucceeded` handler, which blocks the UI thread.

The following example shows how do use `Task` properly:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    Button button = new Button("Get Text");
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        button.setDisable(true);
        Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {

            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                // do long-running operations not modifying the UI
                // here
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                final int count = 10;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    // update message & progress
                    // the messageProperty / progressProperty will be modified on
                    // the javafx application thread
                    updateProgress(i, count);
                    updateMessage("Loading part " + (i+1));

                    // simulate long-running operation
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    sb.append('\n').append(i);
                }
                updateProgress(count, count);
                return sb.toString();
            }

        };

        // while loading, display the task message in the TextArea
        textArea.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

        task.setOnSucceeded(succeededEvent -> {
            // only modifications of the UI here, no longrunning tasks
            textArea.textProperty().unbind();

            // use result of the task
            textArea.setText(task.getValue());

            button.setDisable(false);
        });

        // run task on different thread
        new Thread(task).start();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(textArea, button));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Could updateProgress and updateMessage() be used inside call()? I guess from the naming these methods are changing properties to the main JavaFX thread.

Comment: @pror21 I'm using those methods in the `call` method, ain't I? Those indeed can be called from this method even though it runs on a different thread, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-long-long- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-

Comment: ahh i did not know these methods were part of the task class. Interesting! Thanks again